# How to add an extra field in a post and show it on the template

Tags: custom-field

I'm extremely new to WP. I want to add an extra field to the Post interface and show the content on a template. I don't want to show the content of the Post, but just the content in the extra field.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is design a Customer Testimonial page on my website where I show the full testimonial using the extra field, and show the post content as the mini testimonial if you get what Im saying. Please let me know if I need to clarify more. Thanks heaps. I tried custom fields in WP, but not sure how to grab the extra content only. is there a plug out there for this?

Answer (score 1):

**You can use a custom field eaisly then call into the template**
*(the image shows custom field <-- my installation is in hebrew but would look the same and apears under the editor)*

[image]

Then you can get the value of the field like so...

**Inside the loop**

```
<?php
$key="customField"; 
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
?>
```

**Outside the loop**

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;

// mykey = field name

$key="customField";
$result = get_post_meta($postid, $key, true);
echo $result;
?>
```

.
Hope this helps... i would use custom post type but
this is the easy way to add a field to a post

Good Luck, Sagive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in custom fields in WordPress as mentioned above, I also personally recommend [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). A great plugin with tons of useful documentation and a pretty active support area. Thanks!